# Android-How to add attribute of a file?

Tags: android, attributes, filesystems

I have a demand to **add an attribute of a file** on Android, a document for example, for future use, the attribute is very simple, only a integer, is there an efficient way to do this, especially when to retrieve the added attribute, currently, I am storing the attribute in a database, it is very slow, especially when the number of set files is large.
I wonder is there a way to **increase the speed**, or is it possible to add the attribute on the **file system level**, will this **change the kernel of Android**?